# How to distinguish custom operators from each other?

Tags: syntax, language-design, parsing, operators, operator-overloading

How might one go about building a parser  that can distinguish custom operators in prefix, infix or postfix positions.

For example:

```
# Hypothetical operator
@postfix(Precedence.Not)
let ~ = fn(a) = ...

@infixleft(Precedence.Addition)
let ~^ = fn(a, b) = ...

@prefix(Precedence.Not)
let ^ = fn(a) = ...
```

How can a parser distinguish `a~^b` deterministically?

Is it `~^(a, b)` or `~(a)(^(b))` where a is a single argument function?

Comment: One option is to just  have infix operators

Comment: This is, by definition, a syntactic ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy solution is to require spaces between operators. Alternatively, you could enforce a policy that operators are parsed greedily left-to-right, for example, and then make it the programmer's responsibility to ensure unambiguity

Comment: I fear if I just force spaces in between it might look weird when there are multiple prefix or postfix operators chained. Like: `a * - ~| ^ b` and leaves amguity in determining which one in the chain is an infix.

Comment: @kaiserthe13th Personally I think allowing arbitrary custom operators is almost guaranteed to cause confusion and ambiguity. Even if the language always specifies a specific interpretation to be correct, it's still very easy to get confused and assume another interpretation. One thing that could help in this regard is a smart syntax highlighting plugin that would clearly outline the correct interpretation

Comment: @kaiserthe13th Requiring spaces between operators is a pretty common solution for languages with custom operators, and it's a small sacrifice to make (IMO). Also, programmers will usually put spaces around operators anyway

Comment: If you don't require spaces, then declaring new operators could break existing code.